# Using stages in Azure DevOps Pipeline : Unexpected value 'stages'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I create an Azure-Pipelines file that starts as follows:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

trigger:
- master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  version: '0.2.0'
  azureSubscription: 'Azure.Nupaya'
  azureAppType: 'Web App on Windows'
  webAppName: 'api'

stages:

- stage: 'Prepare'
  displayName: 'Prepare'

  jobs:

  - job: 'Setup'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
      displayName: 'Install'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '2.2.105'
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
 Unexpected value 'stages'
```

Isn't Stages supported in the Yaml File?

I checked the [Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example) in Microsoft Docs ...

What am I missing?

Comment: weird, they were called phases like a month ago, anyway. you mind removing unnecessary linebreaks and see if it helps?

Comment: @4c74356b41 the phases become jobs. Miguel why do you need stages? jobs is not good for you?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk My idea is to have a first stage for Restore, Build, Test, Publish which is triggered by Master branch in a Git repository. And a second to Deploy to Azure but triggered manually. Does this make sense? Is this possible? Can this be done with jobs?

Comment: @MiguelMoura The deployment to azure should be your "Release", not in the Build.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes, exactly but can I make that using a YML file? So I can have that on my Git repository instead of using de Azure DevOps UI? That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Basically I am looking to define Release Pipelines in YAML files.

Comment: Azure DevOps still not support Release YAML :(

Comment: Got it ... I thought it could be possible using only one YAML file. I will be waiting for that option. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 28):

After some playing and testing with the Azure DevOps it seems that you define the **pool** under the **job** property, as to allow us to define different agent pools for different jobs.

So for your example it would be:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  version: '0.2.0'
  azureSubscription: 'Azure.Nupaya'
  azureAppType: 'Web App on Windows'
  webAppName: 'api'

stages:

- stage: 'Prepare'
  displayName: 'Prepare'

  jobs:

  - job: 'Setup'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
      displayName: 'Install'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '2.2.105'
```

Comment: I was getting Unexpected Value 'Jobs'. Followed your structure, and now the error is gone. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was using the key `services:` which must be nested under a job.

The offending code came directly from these [azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). They show `services:` being used directly at the root of the yaml document. However, this only worked in the docs because the implied scope was `job` when no jobs or stages are specified, as in their example. Moving `services:` under the job(s) where it was needed fixed the problem.

Example from Azure Docs:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: my_container
    image: buildpack-deps:focal
  - container: nginx
    image: nginx


pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

container: my_container
services:
  nginx: nginx

steps:
- script: |
    curl nginx
  displayName: Show that nginx is running
```

Notice that they are using `steps:` at the root instead of `stages:`. This caused my problem.

If you run into this problem, or the related problems with `jobs:`, figure out which root key is causing the error by commenting out one key at a time, especially newly added keys. Once you find it, check the [YAML Schema definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) to see if that key is allowed in the scope that's implied. Pay special attention to the implied scope if `steps:`, `jobs:` or `stages:` is used as a root key.

Answer (score 0):

If you find your self with **Unexpected value 'jobs'**, try out stormy structure https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111720/1977871

Mine, which is working is here.

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  finalBuildArtifactName: 'aspnetFrameworkDropFromYaml'

stages:
- stage: 'Prepare'
  displayName: 'Prepare'

  jobs:
  - job: 'BuildPipelineNetFrameworkYaml'
    displayName: 'Build pipeline NetFramework Yaml'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      name: VivekPool1
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      displayName: 'Use NuGet 5 3 1'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 5.3.1

    - script: |
        echo $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) $(build.buildnumber)
        echo $(RestoreBuildProjects)   
        echo $(BuildConfiguration)
        echo The current branch is - $(Build.SourceBranchName)!!!!.
        echo $(finalBuildArtifactName)
      displayName: 'Command Line Script to write out some vars'

    - powershell: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.
        Write-Host "The following are the environment vars."
        get-childitem -path env:*
      displayName: 'PowerShell script to write out env vars'
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet restore'
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build solution'
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
          !**\obj\**
          !**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*SeleniumTest*.dll
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishSymbols@2
      displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
      inputs:
        SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
        PublishSymbols: false
      continueOnError: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy ProvisionNetFramework Files to drop directory'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: Cicd/provisionForNetFramework
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/provisionForNetFramework'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        ArtifactName: '$(finalBuildArtifactName)'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in here.

I had a yellow squiggly line "unexpected value jobs" in this script:

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - master
 batch: true

jobs:
  -job: Build
    pool:
     name: MyAgent
     demands: 
      - MSBuild
      - SqlPackage
```

Can you see the issue?

`-job: Build` should be `- job: Build`

How do people actually use this without their heads exploding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you intend the commands in right way, and that you don't have accidentally `step` on same level as `stages`.
This might happend if you refactor your JSON from a simple *step-based* structure to an "stages-based" structure.

The issue in my case was a missing `step` in front of a `script` declaration inside an stage, and to have a lost `step`-declaration on same level as `stages`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to suther, when I was refactoring, from a job to a stages layout, I was getting "unexpected value 'stages'" and a squiggly line in the editor until I indented the rest of the yaml.

I had both the stages and stage tag in place.