# guide to azure-pipelines.yml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is my first time working with azure pipelines, I started creating my azure-pipeline.yml but i get /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 16, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'

I aligned everything as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```
trigger:
  - master

pr:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages: # this line throws an error and i can't figure out why
- stage: Docker Tag and Push to Registry
  jobs:
  - job: Build and push to Azure Container Registry
    steps:
    - template: az-pipeline-templates/docker-build-tag.yml  # Template reference
- stage: Deploy to US East
  dependsOn: Docker Tag and Push to Registry    # this stage runs after Docker Tag and Push to Registry
  - job: Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
    steps:
    - template: az-pipeline-templates/deploy-to-aks.yml  # Template reference
```

running this will result in:

> /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 16, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111720/5209435) help?

Comment: Multi stages require extra changes as it is in preview, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 16, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'

This error message caused by your `pool` specified. You should not specified the `pool` outside the `stages`.

The correct format should be:

```
trigger:
  - master

pr:
  - master

stages: # this line throws an error and i can't figure out why
- stage: Docker Tag and Push to Registry
  jobs:
  - job: Build and push to Azure Container Registry
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - template: az-pipeline-templates/docker-build-tag.yml  # Template reference
- stage: Deploy to US East
  dependsOn: Docker Tag and Push to Registry    # this stage runs after Docker Tag and Push to Registry
  - job: Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - template: az-pipeline-templates/deploy-to-aks.yml  # Template reference
```